# How to setup redirect url in nginx ingress controller for a swagger endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, swagger, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I am moving to EKS cluster with few microservices. For this we are using Nginx Ingress controller for routing of requests. The ingress object has the following values:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: trial-ingress
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: trial-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /box
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: boxservice-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /branch
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: branchservice-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hello-svc
```

Now, when I browse the loadbalancer address which is something like this **axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-1234564789.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com** I'm able to browse the **httpd** service since it is at root path. But when change the path to **axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-1234564789.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/box** ideally it should redirect me to **boxservice-svc** but it isn't. I get a Not Found error. Same happens with the branch service.

Since all services are microservices in swagger, my actual url changes - `loadbalancer.com/box` would change to `loadbalancer.com/swagger/index.html`
This works flawlessly when I put the service in root path but doesn't work if there is a path like /box or /branch.

Any ideas how can I make use of rewrite rule so that it works with swagger/index.html appended to it?

What I'v tried so far:

1. I've tried to do changes in the ingress yaml definition file so that boxservice is at the **root path "/"** and I'm able to see boxservice swagger page
2. I tried adding the rewrite-rule in the annotations like:
    `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`
   And this does the rewriting of `loadbalancer.com/box` to `loadbalancer.com/swagger/index.html` however the swagger page does not actually loads and I can get an error stating Not Found.

If the above 2nd point works in root path then why not in some proper path?

Am I going in the right direction?